# Iterating row-wise over 2 pandas dataframes and passing these vectors as args to function

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, apply

I'd like to iterate row-wise over 2 identically-shaped dataframes, passing the rows from each as vectors to a function without using loops.  Essentially something similar to R's mapply.

I've investigated a little and the best that I've seen uses map in a list comprehension, but I'm not doing it correctly.  Even if we get this to work, though, it seems a bit clunky - is there a more elegant way to do this?  Seems like this should be a functionality in pandas.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3))

sd_array = np.array([0.02, 0.015, 0.2])

def helper_func(x, y):
   return stats.norm.pdf(x, loc=y, scale=sd_array).prod()

res_lst = []
row_cnt = df1.shape[0]

res = [list(map(helper_func, df1.iloc[i,:], df2.iloc[i,:])) for i in range(row_cnt)]
res_lst.append(res)
```

The way I currently have it written doesn't give an error but also doesn't return what I want.  I should only have 3 values in the output, one for each row of the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do `helper_func(df1, df2)`, and in `helper_func`: `return stats.norm.pdf(x, loc=y, scale=sd_array).prod(axis=1)`. Be aware that your scale is such, that the values returned are almost always 0. Using scale=100*sd_array in the PDF will at least show some non-zero values.

In fact, you don't need a dataframe in this example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(1)

data1 = np.random.randn(3,3)
data2 = np.random.randn(3,3)

sd_array = np.array([0.02, 0.015, 0.2])

C = 100  # for demonstration purposes
def helper_func(x, y):
    return stats.norm.pdf(x, loc=y, scale=C*sd_array).prod(axis=1)

res = helper_func(data1, data2)
print(res)
```

yields

```
array([0.0002616 , 0.00068695, 0.00035566])
```

But when using a dataframe instead of `data1` or `data2`, NumPy/Pandas/Scipy are flexible enough to recognize the 2D array of values and use it as such.

Comment: nice! this is definitely the way to go

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your implementation is that you are iterating over the rows and also applying helper_func to each element in each row using map. So the first call to helper_func is `helpoer_func(df1.iloc[i, 0], df2.iloc[i, 0])`, not on the first row.

You can fix your implementation by removing the inner loop:

```py
res = [helper_func(df1.iloc[i,:], df2.iloc[i,:]) for i in range(row_cnt)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the method in my other answer, using NumPy vector-wise calculations, with `.prod(axis=1)`, but to answer the question in the title: you can use `zip` and `.iterrows()`:

```
assert len(df1) == len(df2)  # just to check
res = [helper_func(row1, row2) for (_, row1), (_, row2) in 
       zip(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows())]
```

(this requires the original `helper_func`, without `axis=1` in the `.prod()` method.)

You need the underscores to ignore the indices that come with `.iterrows()` (it functions as `enumerate()` in standard Python).